# TensorFlow: Dramatic loss of accuracy after freezing graph?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-serving

Is it common to see a dramatic loss of accuracy following the freezing of a graph for serving? During training and evaluation of the flowers dataset using a pretrained inception-resnet-v2, my accuracy is 98-99%, with a probability of 90+% for the correct predictions. However, after freezing my graph and predicting it again, my model was not as accurate and the right labels are only predicted with a confidence of 30-40%.

After model training, I had several items:

1. Checkpoint file
2. model.ckpt.index file
3. model.ckpt.meta file
4. model.ckpt file
5. a graph.pbtxt file.

As I was unable to run the official freeze graph file located in the [tensorflow repository on GitHub](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py) (I guess it was because I have a pbtxt file and not pb file after my training), I am reusing the code from [this tutorial](https://blog.metaflow.fr/tensorflow-how-to-freeze-a-model-and-serve-it-with-a-python-api-d4f3596b3adc) instead.

Here is the code I modified to freeze my graph:

```
import os, argparse

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework import graph_util

dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

def freeze_graph(model_folder, input_checkpoint):
    # We retrieve our checkpoint fullpath
    checkpoint = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(model_folder)
    # input_checkpoint = checkpoint.model_checkpoint_path

    # We precise the file fullname of our freezed graph
    absolute_model_folder = "/".join(input_checkpoint.split('/')[:-1])
    output_graph = absolute_model_folder + "/frozen_model.pb"

    # Before exporting our graph, we need to precise what is our output node
    # This is how TF decides what part of the Graph he has to keep and what part it can dump
    # NOTE: this variable is plural, because you can have multiple output nodes
    output_node_names = "InceptionResnetV2/Logits/Predictions"

    # We clear devices to allow TensorFlow to control on which device it will load operations
    clear_devices = True

    # We import the meta graph and retrieve a Saver
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(input_checkpoint + '.meta', clear_devices=clear_devices)

    # We retrieve the protobuf graph definition
    graph = tf.get_default_graph()
    input_graph_def = graph.as_graph_def()

    # We start a session and restore the graph weights
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        saver.restore(sess, input_checkpoint)

        # We use a built-in TF helper to export variables to constants
        output_graph_def = graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(
            sess, # The session is used to retrieve the weights
            input_graph_def, # The graph_def is used to retrieve the nodes 
            output_node_names.split(",") # The output node names are used to select the usefull nodes
        ) 

        # Finally we serialize and dump the output graph to the filesystem
        with tf.gfile.GFile(output_graph, "wb") as f:
            f.write(output_graph_def.SerializeToString())
        print("%d ops in the final graph." % len(output_graph_def.node))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--model_folder", type=str, help="Model folder to export")
    parser.add_argument("--input_checkpoint", type = str, help = "Input checkpoint name")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    freeze_graph(args.model_folder, args.input_checkpoint)
```

This is the code I use to run my prediction, where I feed in only one image as intended by the user:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from scipy.misc import imread, imresize
import numpy as np

img = imread("./dandelion.jpg")
img = imresize(img, (299,299,3))
img = img.astype(np.float32)
img = np.expand_dims(img, 0)

labels_dict = {0:'daisy', 1:'dandelion',2:'roses', 3:'sunflowers', 4:'tulips'}

#Define the filename of the frozen graph
graph_filename = "./frozen_model.pb"

#Create a graph def object to read the graph
with tf.gfile.GFile(graph_filename, "rb") as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())

#Construct the graph and import the graph from graphdef
with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def)

    #We define the input and output node we will feed in
    input_node = graph.get_tensor_by_name('import/batch:0')
    output_node = graph.get_tensor_by_name('import/InceptionResnetV2/Logits/Predictions:0')

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        predictions = sess.run(output_node, feed_dict = {input_node: img})
        print predictions
        label_predicted = np.argmax(predictions[0])

    print 'Predicted Flower:', labels_dict[label_predicted]
    print 'Prediction probability:', predictions[0][label_predicted]
```

And the output I received from running my prediction:

```
2017-04-11 17:38:21.722217: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:901] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2017-04-11 17:38:21.722608: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:887] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 860M
major: 5 minor: 0 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.0195
pciBusID 0000:01:00.0
Total memory: 3.95GiB
Free memory: 3.42GiB
2017-04-11 17:38:21.722624: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:908] DMA: 0 
2017-04-11 17:38:21.722630: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:918] 0:   Y 
2017-04-11 17:38:21.722642: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:977] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 860M, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
2017-04-11 17:38:22.183204: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/platform_util.cc:58] platform CUDA present with 1 visible devices
2017-04-11 17:38:22.183232: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/platform_util.cc:58] platform Host present with 8 visible devices
2017-04-11 17:38:22.184007: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:183] XLA service 0xb85a1c0 executing computations on platform Host. Devices:
2017-04-11 17:38:22.184022: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:191]   StreamExecutor device (0): <undefined>, <undefined>
2017-04-11 17:38:22.184140: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/platform_util.cc:58] platform CUDA present with 1 visible devices
2017-04-11 17:38:22.184149: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/platform_util.cc:58] platform Host present with 8 visible devices
2017-04-11 17:38:22.184610: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:183] XLA service 0xb631ee0 executing computations on platform CUDA. Devices:
2017-04-11 17:38:22.184620: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:191]   StreamExecutor device (0): GeForce GTX 860M, Compute Capability 5.0
[[ 0.1670652   0.46482906  0.12899996  0.12481128  0.11429448]]
Predicted Flower: dandelion
Prediction probability: 0.464829
```

Potential source of problem: I first trained my model using TF 0.12, but I believe it is compatible with Tf 1.01, the version I'm using now. As a safety precaution, I upgraded my files to TF 1.01 and retrained the model to obtain new sets of checkpoint files (with the same accuracy), and then used these checkpoint files for freezing. I compiled my tensorflow from source. Is the issue coming from the fact that I use a pbtxt file instead of a pb file? I have no idea how I could get a pb file from training my model.

Comment: Just to be sure: the exact same data point scores much better before freezing the graph, right?

Comment: Yes you are right. The scores are much better with a confidence of at least 90% for each correct prediction. With the frozen graph, there is even a wrong prediction sometimes for the same training images I use to predict.

Comment: You should be able to use the standard freeze_graph script with .pbtxt files, it handles both with the --input_binary command line flag. Can you share the error you were seeing when trying to go the official route?

Comment: Hi @PeteWarden I have just tried the official file again and turns out I wrote the checkpoint model name wrongly (i included the characters ".data..." when I shouldn't had). I did not include the input_binary command and everything worked, strangely. The official route works, but I am seeing still a very low accuracy of around 34% where my original was 90+%. Even after performing preprocessing for evaluation, I got only at most a 50% accuracy.

Comment: Also, I thought maybe it's a dataset issue, and so I thought maybe the imagenet dataset should be more consistent, but when I try to predict an image of a class present in the training (kit fox), I get an accuracy of 0.5%. When I evaluated without freezing the graph (using the pure checkpoint model), I get a confidence of around 70% for the top prediction, which was usually something like "arctic fox" or "tabby cat" - either way it is still as close to kit fox than a random class. Here is a gist of the evaluation code: https://gist.github.com/kwotsin/47072ea4ac37ea1098925b82140b66b7

Comment: Alternatively, I have just written a script that restores the checkpoint and does not require the freeze_graph file, as it simply makes use of the current graph to write the variables into constants. Is this equivalent to using freeze_graph? The gist is here: https://gist.github.com/kwotsin/8e43f5db4815e1f1af37da70d0933d8b

Comment: Hi @PeteWarden I figured out the issue comes mainly from how I fed the data into the frozen graph. When I used the feed_dict method, instead of reading a filename as a tensor and decoding it later, it seems to have a lot of problems. After I changed the way I fed the data, everything seems to work fine as expected. However, when I run on an embedded platform like the Jetson TX1, the quantization works very poorly (0% accuracy). I have opened a new thread in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43486394/tensorflow-quantization-of-a-frozen-model-fails-to-work-the-same-on-a-embedded

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is not related to freezing the model. Instead, it is related to the way you pre-process your image.

I recommend you to use the default pre-processing function in InceptionResnet V2.

Below, I will post a code that takes an image path (JPG or PNG) and returns a preprocessed images. You can modify it to make it receive a batch of images. It is not a professional code. It needs some optimization. However, it is working well.

First, Loading the image:

```
def load_img(path_img):
    """
    Load an image to tensorflow
    :param path_img: image path on the disk
    :return: 3D tensorflow image
    """
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([path_img])  # list of files to read

    reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
    key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)

    my_img = tf.image.decode_image(value)  # use png or jpg decoder based on your files.

    init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init_op)

        # Start populating the filename queue.

        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

        for i in range(1):  # length of your filename list
            image = my_img.eval()  # here is your image Tensor :)

        print(image.shape)
        # Image.fromarray(np.asarray(image)).show()

        coord.request_stop()
        coord.join(threads)

        return image
```

Then, the pre-processing code:

```
def preprocess(image, height, width,
               central_fraction=0.875, scope=None):
    """Prepare one image for evaluation.

    If height and width are specified it would output an image with that size by
    applying resize_bilinear.

    If central_fraction is specified it would cropt the central fraction of the
    input image.

    Args:
      image: 3-D Tensor of image. If dtype is tf.float32 then the range should be
        [0, 1], otherwise it would converted to tf.float32 assuming that the range
        is [0, MAX], where MAX is largest positive representable number for
        int(8/16/32) data type (see `tf.image.convert_image_dtype` for details)
      height: integer
      width: integer
      central_fraction: Optional Float, fraction of the image to crop.
      scope: Optional scope for name_scope.
    Returns:
      3-D float Tensor of prepared image.
    """

    image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, dtype=tf.float32)
    # Crop the central region of the image with an area containing 87.5% of
    # the original image.
    if central_fraction:
        image = tf.image.central_crop(image, central_fraction=central_fraction)

    if height and width:
        # Resize the image to the specified height and width.
        image = tf.expand_dims(image, 0)
        image = tf.image.resize_bilinear(image, [height, width],
                                         align_corners=False)
        image = tf.squeeze(image, [0])
    image = tf.subtract(image, 0.5)
    image = tf.multiply(image, 2.0)
    return image
```

Finally, for my case, I had to convert the processed tensor into a numpy array:

```
image = tf.Session().run(image)
```

So, this image can be fed to the freezed model

```
persistent_sess = tf.Session(graph=graph)  # , config=sess_config)

    input_node = graph.get_tensor_by_name('prefix/batch:0')
    output_node = graph.get_tensor_by_name('prefix/InceptionResnetV2/Logits/Predictions:0')

    predictions = persistent_sess.run(output_node, feed_dict={input_node: [image]})
    print(predictions)
    label_predicted = np.argmax(predictions[0])
    print(label_predicted)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and the accuracy was 1.5% lower when using a frozen model. The problem was about the saver object in the code that freeze the model. You need to pass Moving average decay to the saver as an argument. I use the code from Inception model and this is how I create the saver in the freezing script:

```
variable_averages = tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(0.9997)
variables_to_restore = variable_averages.variables_to_restore()
saver = tf.train.Saver(variables_to_restore)
```

For me it solved the problem.